# how do I solve Kivy Launcher recycleview error?

Tags: python, android, kivy, launcher, kivy-recycleview

I have wrote a nice code for a mobile app. Usually I run it on Kivy Launcher and most of the time everything goes well. But recently I have added recycleview and now Kivy Launcher doesnt start my app. I use Logcat. When I run it, it says;

ImportError: No module named recycleview kivy launcher

[image]

my Python version is Python 3.7.0.

I think it is going to fail when I convert it to APK with buildozer as well.

my import line is;

```
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Check your error message. What you posted says `recyclerview`, but that is incorrect spelling.

Comment: I have checked it. It says recycleview. While I am writing this post I accidently wrote recyclerview. Thank you for your observation.